# Quickest way to convert Byte Array into an double Array (using 3 byte integers)

Tags: c#, arrays, byte, bitwise-operators

I have an array of bytes read from a binary file. Currently I convert every 3 bytes into a double using similar code (below)in a loop. At present it can loop through from once to a couple thousand times to produce an array of data.

Dataout = Byte array, FinalData = Double array

```
FinalData[a] = (double)(DataOut[a + k] << 16 | DataOut[a + k + 1] << 8 | DataOut[a + k + 2]) / 10.0;
```

What i would like to know is, are their any quicker ways to do this? maybe using LINQ or some other method to transfer the whole byte array into the double array without needing to loop. I will always need to move a set number of bytes (3 in this example).

Any assistance is much appreciated

Comment: LINQ? Did you mean to tag C#? LINQ isn't magic, by the way.

Comment: Hello, thanks i miss typed. Yeah i know LINQ not magic but i seen similar methods while searching this morning that used LINQ but only for 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

If you could avoid the division by 10.0, that would be the best approach. This is both the slowest operation in your whole process (by far!) and it's inexact. If you don't care about lossiness, you would probably be a lot better off multiplying by 0.1 instead of dividing by 10.0, since multiplication is a lot faster on most machines.

Comment: The division by 0 is kind of needed, although you have made me realise that we could leave it until it needs displaying to the user. Thanks!